# Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.0 reference issues in .NET4.0 VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, .net-4.0, odp.net, data-access

I have an Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.0 version referenced in my project. Whenever I run the project I get an error Could not load the assembly. I checked the entries made in the .csproj file for the referenced dll, and found that the referenced dll was Oracle.DataAccess 2.111.7.0. I am pretty sure the referenced dll is Oracle.DataAccess2.112.1.0 but not sure why the entry made in the project file is different. Any pointers to this would be helpful as this issue has been holding me up for a long time.

Comment: try deleting the reference first, then add it back (using browse).

Comment: tried that a lot but the project file entry still doesnt change. I tried to edit the project file using notepad. But still receive the same error.

Comment: the location and version of the dll can be found in Properties (in References, right click on Oracle.DataAccess and choose Properties)

Comment: I know the location and version and I am sure when I right click the reference it shows a path which is different which is entered in the references section of the project file (.csproj) in my solution. My question is what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the same issue when a client use 2.112.1.0 in their references, but it kept referencing a machine local 2.112.3.0.

The reason is that when installed in the GAC, it inserts a policy file - a GAC level config entry to redirect your DLL to their newer version. Even if you have the file in the same dir, .NET 2+ will check the GAC for any policies before allowing your application to resolve the assembly itself.

Something I tried was a manual redirection in your App/Web.config file, but I found this didn't work for me, which is detailed under [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7wd6ex19.aspx).

Once this is done, you may encounter this issue:

- `BadImageFormatException - Image is not of correct format` (or something similar)

and/or

- `Version mismatch - The major/minor version does not match` (or something similar)

These errors indicate that although your older assembly is now in use, the *COM* assemblies it reference are not expected. My investigation found Oracle ODP.NET assemblies stores its COM DLL versions hard-coded within.

The only solution that did for me, was to

1. Un-GAC the 2.112.X.0 that your app was auto-referencing.
2. Copy the version specific COM DLLs to a different directory (like \LIB)
3. Copy them into the build, as you build

If this all fails, I would recommend completely uninstalling the Oracle ODP.NET, deleting the Oracle directory manually and then after rebooting, installing the old DLL from the MSI directly. Oracle seem to have stored the whole history of drivers online at [Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html).

Good luck!